# Android Webview Localization

Tags: android, localization, webview

I am new to development and would firstly like to thanks all contributors to this site, it has been extremely helpful.

OK, I have a webview within a tabview and would like to set the webview url relevant the users localization: ie i would like to set a url for UK users, a URL for USA users and so on.

The code in my activity is currently:

```
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);   
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.mywebviewurl.com");
```

I have read android and stackoverflow forums but i just can't seem to get this working.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks
Stephen

*IGNORE: worked it out, thanks anyway.**

Comment: Stephen, you may want to consider posting how you solved your problem.  It may be helpful to a future visitor!  You can post and accept an answer to your own question.

Comment: Have got solution for your Question? @Stephen